# Responsive imgs of different widths with same height

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase what I need, but basically I have three different images that I'd like to remain the same ratio, but they aren't the same size. I guess it looks like this:

`|------| |----------| |--| 
| Img1 | |  Img2    | | 3| 
|------| |----------| |--|`

And have them scale responsively. Here's the HTML and CSS:

```css
    @media all and (max-width: 775px) {
     .aboutbody, .sidebar {
      display: block;
     }
    
     .sidebar {
      width: 86%;
      margin-left: 7%;
      height: 300px;
     }
    
     .sidebarpics {
      height: 200px;
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
     }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="sidebar">
        <img class="sidebarpics" img src="assets/family1.jpg">
        <img class="sidebarpics" src="assets/speaking1.jpg">
        <img class="sidebarpics" src="assets/family2.jpg">
    </div>
```

Here's the website that I'm updating in real time. http://hanksmith.com/about.php
To understand you need to shrink the browser window until the three pictures at the side move to the top.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you want in the end. But I'll guess you want all 3 Images next to each other with the same height. 
But now comes the difficult part. At which ratio? Are you allowed to stretch and squish images out of their ratio? Since all of them have different ones.

Comment: You could give the `sidebarpics` div a `width: 30%` and a `height: auto`? That would however as mentioned above make one picture taller than the others. Squishing doesn't seem like an option though..

Comment: If it's possible, I'd like to keep them at the same ratio that they are. So have one image covering 20% of the div, one covering 60%, and one covering 40% (not exact numbers), and then all the same height so it's flush.

Comment: @Goombah OP mentioned that all the images should be the same height. If thats the case, it comes at the cost of either cutting something or stretching the images out of ration.

Comment: Assuming you want the images un-stretched and not cropped, it's not possible with CSS if you also want to set a fixed height. If that's what you want, you'd have to resort to JS. If a set height isn't as important as getting the effect with pure CSS, I can provide an answer.

Comment: yes, as @TheThirdMan said if you dont worry about the image stretch/shrink, just remove width:auto from your css class '.sidebarpics', it will give you all the images same height and width!

Comment: @TheThirdMan I'd be totally fine with using a JS or even JQuery solution. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **vertical alignment top** .
ignore playing with height, play with width in percentage.

```
 @media (max-width: 775px){
.sidebarpics {
    max-width: 32%;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-height: 100px;
}
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Although it's not perfect, it works well enough. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thats about the same as I suggested. Here you trading "not cutting off" against ugly white-space between the images on a horizontal layer.

Comment: @BJohnson: I don't see how this solves your problem, as it won't stretch all the images to the entire width available, "just" make all the same height (unless you also set their width manually). That's alright if this is what you were looking for, but I understood your question differently.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Yeah, it wasn't entirely what I wanted, but I just needed a way to fix it quick. I might come back later when the website is working and fix it then. I ended up doing the width manually as percentages so it still reflexively and responsively shrinks and grows.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest giving them a percentage width, to each child there own width to make them take the available space.

Something like this:

```
.sidebarpics:nth-child(1)
{
    width: 18%;
    height: auto;
}

.sidebarpics:nth-child(2)
{
    width: 36%;
    height: auto;
}

.sidebarpics:nth-child(3)
{
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the aspect ratio is the problem.

There are many solutions to it but i would suggest using 3 small versions and show them instead of them on smaller screens. If you like the idea then i can write you some code.

Comment: I think this might be my best option. I'd love to try out your code. Thanks!

Comment: Oh using the picture tag here would be a great idea. But including diffrent img Elements for different breakpoints not as much.

Answer (score 1):

You can just limit max-width for every image:

```
@media (max-width: 775px) {
  .sidebarpics {
     max-width: 32%;
     display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `flex`

```
.sidebar {
     display: flex;
}
```

and give each image a percentage width.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxjpwbus/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you using `@media` query to share your images. You can share their width in `%`

**Try doing this**

```
@media all and (max-width: 775px) {
.aboutbody, .sidebar {
    display: block;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 86%;
    margin-left: 7%;
    height: 300px;
}

.sidebarpics:first-child  {
    height: 200px;
    width: 30%; /*share the two imgs to any % you like*/
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sidebarpics:nth-child(2) {
    height: 200px;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sidebarpics:last-child {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.sidebarpics:first-child  {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
.sidebarpics:nth-child(2) {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sidebarpics:last-child {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to manage the following:

- keeping ratio of images individually
- all the same height
- not cutting anything of the image

If the last point is something you can get away with, I'd suggest the following.
Use a defined height on the parent container, and overflow: hidden; to cut off everything above the height.
The images are aligned to the top and have a max-width, to make sure they fit next to each other. If you don't mind upscaling, use width instead.

```
.sidebar {
    height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 33%;
}
```